# Create sub directory within all directories Command prompt

Tags: command-line, cmd

I have been tasked to create sub-folders within folders containing letters a and ar using CMD.
Folder structure: grand parent - parent - this is what I need to target (all folders) - their children with folder name containing "ar".

I am trying this :

FOR /d %A IN (c:\Grandparent\Parent\ * \ *ar*) DO mkdir "%A\item_one" "%A\item_two" "%A\item_three" "%\item_four"

So, trying to use wild card to select all folders within a folder, but it doesn't seem to work. (star right after "Parent")

Any help would be much appreciated.

Note : I am not allowed to use batch files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you need `FOR /D` here. When you are satisfied that the correct directories will be made, remove `echo` from the `MKDIR` command.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\src\*ar*"`) DO (FOR %b IN (item_one item_two item_three item_four) DO (echo MKDIR "%~a\%~b"))
```

Formatted for better readability, it looks like:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\src\*ar*"`) DO (
    FOR %b IN (item_one item_two item_three item_four) DO (
        echo MKDIR "%~a\%~b"
    )
)
```

If you really want to stick with one `MKDIR` command, you could do the following. However, I suggest that the previous way is more maintainable. Given that you cannot use .bat script files, I am not sure if maintainability is an issue.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %a IN (`DIR /S /B /A:D "C:\src\*ar*"`) DO (
    echo MKDIR "%~a\item_one" "%~a\item_two" "%~a\item_three" "%~a\item_four"
)
```